# How to put the condition on an array that at least one element of it should be a specific integer in C language?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, loops

For example I have a one dimensional array integers as its elements and I want to make sure that at least one of the element in the array is 5.
How can I achieve this in C language ?

Comment: Have you tried a `for` loop?

Comment: iterate through array elements and compare one with 5

Comment: Statically (i.e. enforced by the compiler)? You can't.

Answer (score 2):

You can write such a function yourself.

Here is a demonstrative program. The function is called `any_of` like the corresponding algorithm in C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int /* _Bool */ any_of( const int a[], size_t n, int value )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n && a[i] != value ) i++;

    return i != n;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    int value = 5;

    printf( "The array contains %d is %s\n", 
            value, 
            any_of( a, N, value ) != 0 ? "true" : "false"  );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
The array contains 5 is true
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic question, however, here's an example, I hope it'll help you in your programming efforts

```
int main()
{
    int a[5] = { 1,2,3,5,3 };
    bool fiveFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        if (5 == a[i]) {
            printf("At least one element of the array is 5");
            fiveFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!fiveFound) {
        printf("Array doesn't contain 5");
    }
}
```

I'd also suggest you to read *The C Programming Language (Second edition)* by Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie, and do some online tutorials

Comment: Thanks for the help, actually I'm beginner in the programming world.

Comment: @underdog_eagle here's a link to good book list on C http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list, also, a stackoverflow way to say thanks is accepting the answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such shortcut for that in C [And I think not even in any language]. But if you really want this fuctinality you may find it easier to write a function to check whether the element exists in the array or not.

Answer (score -2):

You need to iterate through the elements of the array:

```
#define SIZE 5

int main() {
    int array[SIZE] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};
    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++){
        if (array[i] == 5)
            printf("Found it!\n");
            return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: check the `printf()` statement

Comment: @Aleins be careful of undefined behaviour, and you're doing just that when not initializing the array before using it

Comment: @cherubim anand what do you mean?

Comment: @buld0zzr fixed now

Comment: BTW please try to get into the habit of putting the `newline` at the other end of your `printf` statements, such as `printf("Found it!\n");` That way, you can be sure they reach the terminal. And if you ever insert debugging cues, without that you can't be certain to get the right messages before a crash. (This fixes @CherubimAnand comment too).

Comment: The answer from @VladfromMoscow is the equivalent of the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which is requested of those asking a question. It is complete (has the header), is compilable, and is verifiable by changing the `5` in the array.

Comment: @Weather Vane I like having the '/n' at the beginning of printfs. In my experience, this is the most purposeful way to do it. It's basically a question of preference

Comment: No it's a question of functionality.